# How to use freeradius as radius translator

Tags: freeradius

i have configured strongswan (ipsec) to send request to freeradius as eap-radius.
and i configured freeradius to send requests using proxy to another radius server. (IBSng).

but , ipsec sends as EAP and freeradius forwards the original request to ibsng. ibsng didn't understand EAP ! just need clear text password.

how can i translate EAP to clear-text password in proxy?

Comment: Hi @mihanservice - you probably want to put this up on https://serverfault.com/, which is the sysadmin community. StackOverflow is for programming, it won't be much use for your question ;)

Comment: @oblio FreeRADIUS implements its own policy language "unlang".  It's appropriate to post FreeRADIUS questions on stack overflow as they often involve developing "unlang" scripts.

Comment: Which EAP method are you using?

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell ok. But he still needs to edit his message and maybe even post some code, to me at least it's not very clear what he wants.